# make two array as one

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have two array 
the first one is

```
lineChart = [{type : 'line' , data : arrdata }] ;
```

second one is

```
mina = [{type : 'area' , data : [[1326844575000,10] ,[1326845955000,10]], color : 'H33FF00'},
        {type : 'area' , data : [[1326846575000,10] ,[1326848065000,10]], color : 'H33FF00'},
        {type : 'area' , data : [[1326848390000,10] ,[1326849755000,10]], color : 'H33FF00'} ];
```

when i push them together like :

```
mychart.push(lineChart);
mychart.push(mina); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(mychart)) ;
```

this is what i get

```
[{"type":"line","data":[]},[{"type":"area","data":[[1326844575000,10],[1326845955000,10]],"color":"H33FF00"},{"type":"area","data":[[1326846575000,10],[1326848065000,10]],"color":"H33FF00"},{"type":"area","data":[[1326848390000,10],[1326849755000,10]],"color":"H33FF00"}]]
```

**My question is: How to make this result array as one array like this?**

```
[{"type":"line","data":[]},{"type":"area","data":[[1326844575000,10],[1326845955000,10]],"color":"H33FF00"},{"type":"area","data":[[1326846575000,10],[1326848065000,10]],"color":"H33FF00"},{"type":"area","data":[[1326848390000,10],[1326849755000,10]],"color":"H33FF00"}]
```

Comment: `lineChart` is not an array, it's an Object. Please learn the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just push the first object into the array.

`mina.push(linechart);`

Also, if you specifically want the linechart at the beginning use 
`mina.unshift(linechart);`

http://jsfiddle.net/E2WT8/

```
mina = [{type : 'area' , data : [[1326844575000,10] ,[1326845955000,10]], color : 'H33FF00'},
        {type : 'area' , data : [[1326846575000,10] ,[1326848065000,10]], color : 'H33FF00'},
        {type : 'area' , data : [[1326848390000,10] ,[1326849755000,10]], color : 'H33FF00'} ];

lineChart = {type : 'line' , data : [] } ;

mina.unshift(lineChart);

alert(JSON.stringify(mina)) ;
```

Comment: @MinaGabriel here is a working jsfiddle can you explain what's not working? http://jsfiddle.net/E2WT8/

Comment: can you put this in an answer cause this is the write one i wanted to give you credit

Comment: @MinaGabriel both answers are correct (because you wrote `this is the write one`). Here is an jsfiddle of mine: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zwkx/ , but it's true, that qw3n's answer was faster.

Answer (score 1):

First: `lineChart` is no array, it's an object.

`mina` is an array.

To add `lineChart` you can use `mina.push(lineChart);`.

Another way is `var mychart = mina.concat([lineChart]);`

Another solution is too merge them:

```
function arrayMerge(array1, array2) {
    var i, j, newArray = []; for(i=0,j=array1.length;i<j;++i) {
        newArray.push(array1[i]);
    }
    for(i=0,j=array2.length;i<j;++i) {
        newArray.push(array2[i]);
    }

    return newArray;
}

var mergedArray = arrayMerge(mina, [lineChart]);
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zwkx/